# Passing Vue data to php

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to pass a data from vue props to php code. My code looks something like this:`<input type="text" value="" @{{props.correct}} class="d-none" name="correct">`

Comment: Vue is javascript and javascript talks with php by ajax

Comment: please specify the php code? controller or blade or something else?

Comment: i used the blade

Comment: actually, i just want to put the value of the props.question as the value of the input element

Comment: i see. are they on othe same file ? <input type="text" :value="@{{props.correct}}" class="d-none" name="correct"> bind the value if not then u need to pass the variable to your parent component until it reaches where you put your vue on your blade then call like that. i assume since you use blade they are on the same blade/file all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried binding property with `attribute` name?

```
<input type="text" value="" :attribute-name="props.correct" class="d-none" name="correct">
```

Comment: my bad, it should be like this   <input type="text" v-bind:value="props.correct" class="d-none" name="correct">

Comment: Yeah, you can use v-bind with any attribute, like value also.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass vue (input) data to PHP by using AJAX Request (e.g. you can sending them as json to your server)